# Fetch data from a model and table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model and a table in the database (MySQL). There is a common column in both the tables. I am writing a database query using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql
  where 
    sql = "select table_1.common_column, table_1.column_1, table_1.column_2, table_2.column_1, table_2.column_1"
```

This gives a result as an array of arrays with 5 columns in each array.

So, I have 2 questions

1. Will all the array have data in the same sequence like `[common_column, table_1.column_1, table_1.column_2, table_2.column_1, table_2.column_1]`?
2. Is there any effective way that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables by `common_column` and use select to indetify table columns. In my example I've `questions` and `jobs` table with common column `user_id`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  Question.
    joins('INNER JOIN answers ON questions.asker_id = answers.answerer_id').
    select('questions.*, answers.*'))
```

In `select` you can be more detailed and alias column

```
select('questions.description as q_desc, answers.description as ans_desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to use `includes`, `preload`, `eager_load` methods. Here is nice [article about it](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

Example of usage:

```
Question.includes(:answers).find_each do |question|
  do_something_with_question_columns(question.column_1, question.column_2, ...)
  question.answers.each do |answer|
     do_something_with_answer_columns(answer.column_2, answer.column_2, ...)
  end
end
```

Comment: But this will work only if there is association between the models, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, do you have model classes for these tables?

Comment: No models. 
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql_query) gave the result as a hash with column names so that worked for me.